# Tail keeps snapping to the bottom after i scroll up with mousewheel

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu, tail

I'm having a problem with tail in Xubuntu (Xfce 4).  In my previous ubuntu install (Ubuntu 9.10), if i was tailing a file with `tail -f myfile`, i could scroll up with the mousewheel to look at an earlier part of the file.

Now though, if it's a file which is being updated while i look at it (like a log file) whenever any new text is updated to the end of the file, the view snaps down to the bottom again, away from the part i was looking at.

This is really annoying, does anyone know how i can change the behaviour?

thanks, max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe trying a different terminal window will help? Ubuntu normally uses Terminal from Gnome I think. And in xfce it might just use different software that **does** the scrolling down thing when using tail? Try to install a different Terminal application and see

Comment: ah yes, i think you're right - the one i'm using now is `Xfce Terminal Emulator 0.4.3` whereas before it would have been a gnome one like you say.  Off to hunt for that then...

Comment: Yep, that was it: installed "Terminal (gnome-terminal)" via the ubuntu software centre, looks the same but it's the old one alright.  Thanks!

Comment: That was just a shot in the blue, I don't even use Linux ;D

Comment: One of those things that seems obvious in hindsight :)