# Any way to stream a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, stdout

I have a terminal output which I'd like to be available to several users

currently something like:

```
command > /var/logs
```

for the input, and:

```
watch tail -30 /var/logs
```

for the input terminals.

however this is undesirable because watch only polls as opposed to outputting when there is updates and tail doesn't allow scrollback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two problems you posit:

> watch only polls as opposed to outputting when there are updates

`tail -f` does not poll. As of version 7.5 of GNU Coreutils, `tail -f` will use the Linux kernel's `inotify` interface to receive signals from the kernel indicating that the file has been modified. If you don't use GNU Coreutils, or use a version older than 7.5 for some reason, it will poll once per second. It probably also polls on non-Linux POSIX operating systems (BSD, Solaris, etc) but you would have to research it on a case-by-case basis: some of these OSes use GNU Coreutils but the kernel doesn't support `inotify`; some of them don't use GNU Coreutils to implement `tail` at all.

> tail doesn't allow scrollback

The `less` command is specifically designed to buffer data from `stdin` (e.g. from the `tail` command) and allow you to scroll back and forth. The buffer is not unlimited, but you can use command line options to increase or decrease the buffer as well as modify how long the buffer is for back-scroll and forward-scroll.

So something like, maybe,

`tail -f /var/logs | less`

would allow you to keep a scrollback buffer of the logs without polling (`tail` just sits there idle consuming no CPU until the kernel tosses it a signal letting it know that the file has been modified).

If you need multiple users to be able to read from the same buffer, you could just run `tail -f /var/logs` within a `screen` session. My original answer didn't take into account that you want to run this so that multiple users can see the same log data at the same time. @Let_Me_Be mentioned `screen` and then it occurred to me that that's probably your best bet.

So putting my solution and @Let_Me_Be's solution together:

`screen -mdS logview -- tail -f /var/logs`

Warning: Untested. Please edit if it's wrong. But I think we're close on the trail to a proper solution here.

Now you just need to have `screen` in multi-user mode. This is a little complicated, so I'll let [this](http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser) site speak for itself. The gist is that you have to add `multiuser on` to your `~/.screenrc` file. Also see the **Common Problems** at the bottom of that link.

Now, for users to view the log:

`screen -rS logview`

should do it.

Comment: Also, have a look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/458997/cant-scroll-tail-up-or-down-on-server/460049#460049) question, apparently less has an option to wait for and display new data (just like tail -f).

Answer (score 3):

You want a program like `screen` or `tmux`.